# Is there another way to reduce the array to a single number

Tags: javascript, arrays

reduced an array to a single number by multiplication of all numbers, but i get the wrong output

let numbs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

let reducedNumb = numbs.reduce((prevVal, currVal)=>
prevVal * currVal
,0)

console.log(reducedNumb); //output is 0

Comment: Second param should be 1.

Comment: You're multiplying all the numbers by an additional number that wasn't part of the assignment.

Comment: the second argument to `.reduce` is the starting number, so you're starting with 0 and `0*x` is always 0. You need to change 0 to 1 for the identity property of multiplication

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple math mistake. Something times 0 is always 0 ;)

```
let reducedNumb = numbs.reduce((prevVal, currVal)=> prevVal * currVal ,1)
```